# Autosuggest not working properly because of division overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is an input field on which I have used auto suggest. There is a div tag just below the input field which shows the suggestions when a alphabet is entered. But there is also another division present just below the input field where some results after the form submission will show up. Because these two divisions are overlapping I cannot click on the suggestions.

Input tag

```
<input type="text" id="book" name="book"  placeholder="BOOK" 
                class="input1"  autocomplete="off"><br><br>

<div class="autodropdown">
<ul class="suggestresult"></ul>

</div>
```

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#book').keyup(function(){
    var query_string = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_book.php",
        data: { name:query_string },

        success: function(data)
        { 
            $('.suggestresult').html(data);
            $('.suggestresult li').click(function(){
                var return_value = $(this).text();
                $('#book').attr('value', return_value); 
                $('#book').val(return_value);
                $('.suggestresult').html('');
            });
        }
    });
});

});
```

css file

```
.autodropdown{position:absolute;
top:32%;
left:9%;}

.suggestresult{
width:270px;
list-style:none;
}

.suggestresult li{

padding:15px;
border:1px solid #333;
border-top:0;
cursor:pointer;
background:#333;
color:#fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}

.suggestresult li:hover{
background:#666;
color:#ffffff;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

division just below the input field

```
<div id="adiv1" class="adiv"></div>
```

with css

```
#adiv1{
  width:250px;
  height:400px;
  /* background-color:white; */
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  left:12%;
  color:white;
  font-size:24px;
  }
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I have added all the required code except php because that is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting .suggestresult position to relative and the z-index of the two divs:

```
.autodropdown{position:absolute;
top:32%;
left:9%;
z-index: 2;
}

.suggestresult{
width:270px;
list-style:none;
position: relative;
z-index: 1
}
```

*Edit: Or the other way around, depending on what you are trying to achieve her...*

Comment: It worked!! Thankyou. Also can you tell me how can i click the suggestions and get cursor along with the clicked result into the field. I am able to get clicked suggestion into the field but not the cursor.

Comment: @JatinLalwani I haven't used jQuery in years, but try adding `$('#book').focus();` beneath `$('#book').val(return_value);`

Comment: Dude you are a champ! thank you bro..Now I can submit my project on time..God bless :)

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if solved your problem :)